# sonar fails to upgrade database

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to upgrade sonar from version 2.11 to 3.5 but at the end sonar fail to upgrade database. I'm using the war installation of sonar with tomcat 5.5 and database having mysql.

I'm getting following error in sonar.log file after hitting url http://xx.xx.xx.xx/sonar/setup and click on Upgrade button.

Please help me if anybody has any idea to resolve this problem.

```
2013.06.20 16:10:34 ERROR o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade  Fail to render: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8887/sonar/setup/setup_database
undefined method `exists?' for #<ActionController::Session::JavaServletStore:0x150fa46>
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:107:in `exists?'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:124:in `load_for_read!'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:57:in `[]'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/verification.rb:106:in `verify_presence_of_keys_in_hash_flash_or_params'
        org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:571:in `find'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/verification.rb:106:in `verify_presence_of_keys_in_hash_flash_or_params'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/verification.rb:99:in `prereqs_invalid?'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/verification.rb:91:in `verify_action'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/verification.rb:83:in `verify'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:225:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:629:in `run_before_filters'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in `call_filters'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2105:in `send'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
        org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:42:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:39:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/temp/0-sonar/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/rack/adapter/rails.rb:36:in `serve_rails'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/rack/adapter/rails.rb:41:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/jruby/rack/rails.rb:185:in `call'
        /usr/local/velocity-qa/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/work/Catalina/localhost/sonar/loader/rack/handler/servlet.rb:19:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 5 is not supported any longer. Please check the [requirements page for Sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements).